# Extremely simple Ajax code doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The external website spits proper JSON and the code is too simple I don't know what can be wrong. I tried with get and post.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.get("https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/demo_ajax_json.js", function(result) {
    alert(result);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: because it's cross domain - learn about CORS - also w3schools lives up to it's reputation as a crap resource - no content-type header in the response

Comment: Remember to view your console (`F12` in chrome) to view any error messages.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to access from localhost append this line 
http://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ else keep it like https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/demo_ajax_json.js and then use $.getJson , it will output the result as you required , also JSON.stringify the JSON data so that you can view the data in alert else [Object][Object] will be alerted

```
var resultUrl = 'http://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/'+'https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/demo_ajax_json.js';

    $.getJSON(resultUrl, function(result) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(result));
    });
```